# Magento2: programmatically add layout for specific products

Tags: magento2, layout, xml

Good evening.

I need to add layout for products, which SKUs start from 9 (so 9XXXX).

I've read we can add this though handler or some other methods.

If someone had experience with that moment, please give answer.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try the following way:

> app/code/SR/MagentoCommunity/etc/frontend/events.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="layout_load_before">
        <observer name="add_custom_layout_handle" instance="SR\MagentoCommunity\Observer\LayoutLoadBefore"/>
    </event>
</config>
```

> app/code/SR/MagentoCommunity/Observer/LayoutLoadBefore.php

```
<?php
namespace SR\MagentoCommunity\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer;
use Magento\Framework\Registry;

class LayoutLoadBefore implements ObserverInterface
{
    /**
     * @var Registry
     */
    protected $registry;

    /**
     * LayoutLoadBefore constructor.
     * @param Registry $registry
     */
    public function __construct(
        Registry $registry
    ) {
        $this->registry = $registry;
    }

    /**
     * @param Observer $observer
     * @return $this
     */
    public function execute(Observer $observer)
    {
        $action = $observer->getData('full_action_name');
        if ($action != 'catalog_product_view') {
            return $this;
        }

        /** @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $product */
        $product = $this->registry->registry('product');
        if (!$product) {
            return $this;
        }

        /** @var \Magento\Framework\View\LayoutInterface $layout */
        $layout = $observer->getData('layout');
        if (strpos($product->getSku(), '9') === 0) {
            $layout->getUpdate()->addHandle('catalog_product_view_custom');
        }

        return $this;
    }
}
```

> app/code/SR/MagentoCommunity/view/frontend/layout/catalog_product_view_custom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" name="sample_test_template" as="sample_test_template" template="SR_MagentoCommunity::product/view/sample.phtml"/>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

> app/code/SR/MagentoCommunity/view/frontend/templates/product/view/sample.phtml

```
<h1>This is Sample Template</h1>
```